# Transact-SQL transaction rollback not working properly when using GO commands

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a migration script written in Transact-SQL which is using transactions in order to have a proper rollback if something goes wrong during the execution.
Unfortunately, this rollback behaviour is not working as expected when I'm using some GO utility statements in my script.

The issue can be reproduced with a simple script:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Create a table with two nullable columns
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](36) NULL
)

-- add one row having one NULL column
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t1] VALUES(NEWID(), NULL)

-- set one column as NOT NULLABLE
-- this fails because of the previous insert
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t1] ALTER COLUMN [name] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
GO

-- create a table as next action, so that we can test whether the rollback happened properly
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
)
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

When I execute this script, I get the following output:

```
(1 row affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'name', table 'test-transaction.dbo.t1'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
```

As expected, it is complaining that the column 'name' contains a NULL value but only the corresponding GO batch fails. The next batch is executed and the table t2 is successfully created.

My understanding of the [GO documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) is that it should not impact the T-SQL transactions but this is not the case in my example.
How can I make the whole transaction be rolled back if any of the GO batch fails?

ps: if I remove the GO statements, the transaction rollback is working as expected. But I do need those GO statements, in order to ensure that some parts of the script are executed before others.

Answer (score 2):

Some errors roll back the transaction.  Don't bother figuring out which ones, because there's no simple rule.

A multi-batch script should have a single error handler scope that rolls back the transaction on error, and commits at the end.  In TSQL you can do this with dynamic sql, eg

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    EXEC('
    -- Create a table with two nullable columns
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
        [id] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
        [name] [nvarchar](36) NULL
    )
    ')

    EXEC('
    -- add one row having one NULL column
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[t1] VALUES(NEWID(), NULL)
    ')
    -- set one column as NOT NULLABLE
    -- this fails because of the previous insert
    EXEC('
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t1] ALTER COLUMN [name] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
    ')

    EXEC('
    -- create a table as next action, so that we can test whether the rollback happened properly
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
        [id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
    )
    ')

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
  THROW;
END CATCH
```

With SQLCMD you can use the `-b` option to abort the script on error.

Comment: Does the order make any difference for the BEGIN TRANSACTION and BEGIN TRY?

Comment: No.  It does not matter.

Comment: Thanks @David. We use that structure a lot but have them the other way around (so that the try/catch is 'outer'). We tested to find any differences and we couldn't find any, but I was wondering if there was any technical reason or edge case to have it that way. Good to know there's not.

Comment: Is there a way to still use "GO" and avoid the dynamic SQL part? Having the actual contents of the script as this kind of free-text is rather inconvenient.

Comment: You can use SQLCMD with -b to run the script. Or roll your own script runner.

Comment: If SQLCMD is not available, is there another way to enforce the script being executed from top to bottom, e.g. maybe without `GO` statements?

Comment: SSMS always executes all the batches in the script.  You're using SSMS, why wouldn't SQLCMD, or the Invoke-SqlCmd powershell cmdlet be available?