# Flyway fail on error in Transact-SQL migration

Tags: t-sql, flyway

When using Flyway in combination with a Microsoft SQL Server, we are observing the issue described on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64563382/5127499).

Basically, a migration script like this one does not rollback the successful `GO`-delimited batches when another part failed:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Create a table with two nullable columns
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](36) NULL
)

-- add one row having one NULL column
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t1] VALUES(NEWID(), NULL)

-- set one column as NOT NULLABLE
-- this fails because of the previous insert
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t1] ALTER COLUMN [name] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
GO

-- create a table as next action, so that we can test whether the rollback happened properly
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
)
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

In the above example, the table `t2` is being created even though the preceding `ALTER TABLE` statement fails.

On the linked question, the following approaches (outside of the flyway context) were suggested:

1. > A multi-batch script should have a single error handler scope that rolls back the transaction on error, and commits at the end. In TSQL you can do this with dynamic sql

   - *Dynamic SQL makes for hard-to-read script and would be very inconvenient*
2. > With SQLCMD you can use the `-b` option to abort the script on error

   - **Is this available in flyway?**
3. > Or roll your own script runner

   - **Is this maybe the case in flyway? Is there a flyway-specific configuration to enable proper failing on errors?**

---

*EDIT: alternative example*

#### Given: simple database

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE [a] (
    [a_id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [a_name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [b] (
    [b_id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [a_name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [a] VALUES (NEWID(), 'name-1');
INSERT INTO [b] VALUES (NEWID(), 'name-1'), (NEWID(), 'name-2');

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

#### Migration Script 1 (failing, without GO)

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION

ALTER TABLE [b] ADD [a_id] [nvarchar](36) NULL;

UPDATE [b] SET [a_id] = [a].[a_id] FROM [a] WHERE [a].[a_name] = [b].[a_name];

ALTER TABLE [b] ALTER COLUMN [a_id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE [b] DROP COLUMN [a_name];

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This results in the error message `Invalid column name 'a_id'.` for the `UPDATE` statement.
Possible solution: introduce `GO` between statements

#### Migration Script 2 (with GO: working for "happy case" but only partial rollback when there's an error)

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [b] ADD [a_id] [nvarchar](36) NULL;
GO
UPDATE [b] SET [a_id] = [a].[a_id] FROM [a] WHERE [a].[a_name] = [b].[a_name];
GO
ALTER TABLE [b] ALTER COLUMN [a_id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE [b] DROP COLUMN [a_name];
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

- This performs the desired migration as long as all values in table `[b]` have a matching entry in table `[a]`.
- In the given example, that's not the case. I.e. we get two errors:

  - expected: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'a_id', table 'test.dbo.b'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.`
  - unexpected: `The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.`
  - **Horrifyingly: the last `ALTER TABLE [b] DROP COLUMN [a_name]` statement was actually executed, committed and not rolled back.** I.e. one cannot fix this up afterwards as the linking column is lost.

This behaviour is actually independent of flyway and can be reproduced directly via SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited 20201102 -- learned a lot more about this and largely rewrote it! So far have been testing in SSMS, do plan to test in Flyway as well and write up a blog post. For brevity in migrations, I believe you could put the @@trancount check / error handling into a stored procedure if you prefer, that's also on my list to test.*

### Ingredients in the fix

For error handling and transaction management in SQL Server, there are three things which may be of great help:

- Set XACT_ABORT to ON (it is off by default). This setting "specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a runtime error" [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql)
- Check @@TRANCOUNT state after each batch delimiter you send and using this to "bail out" with RAISERROR / RETURN if needed
- Try/catch/throw -- I'm using RAISERROR in these examples, Microsoft recommends you use THROW if it's available to you (it's available SQL Server 2016+ I think) - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql)

### Working on the original sample code

Two changes:

- Set XACT_ABORT ON;
- Perform a check on @@TRANCOUNT after each batch delimiter is sent to see if the next batch should be run. The key here is that if an error has occurred, @@TRANCOUNT will be 0. If an error hasn't occurred, it will be 1. (Note: if you explicitly open multiple "nested" transactions you'd need to adjust trancount checks as it can be higher than 1)

In this case the @@TRANCOUNT check clause will work even if XACT_ABORT is off, but I believe you want it on for other cases. (Need to read up more on this, but I haven't come across a downside to having it ON yet.)

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
GO

-- Create a table with two nullable columns
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](36) NULL
)

-- add one row having one NULL column
INSERT INTO [dbo].[t1] VALUES(NEWID(), NULL)

-- set one column as NOT NULLABLE
-- this fails because of the previous insert
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t1] ALTER COLUMN [name] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
GO

IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @ErrorMessage
        = N'Transaction in an invalid or closed state (@@TRANCOUNT=' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
          + N'). Exactly 1 transaction should be open at this point.  Rolling-back any pending transactions.';
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 127);
    RETURN;
END;

-- create a table as next action, so that we can test whether the rollback happened properly
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NOT NULL
)
GO


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

### Alternative example

*I added a bit of code at the top to be able to reset the test database. I repeated the pattern of using XACT_ABORT ON and checking @@TRANCOUNT after each batch terminator (GO) is sent.*

```sql
/* Reset database */

USE master;
GO

IF DB_ID('transactionlearning') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE transactionlearning
    SET SINGLE_USER
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE transactionlearning;
END;
GO
CREATE DATABASE transactionlearning;
GO


/* set up simple schema */
USE transactionlearning;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE [a]
(
    [a_id] [NVARCHAR](36) NOT NULL,
    [a_name] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [b]
(
    [b_id] [NVARCHAR](36) NOT NULL,
    [a_name] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [a]
VALUES
(NEWID(), 'name-1');
INSERT INTO [b]
VALUES
(NEWID(), 'name-1'),
(NEWID(), 'name-2');

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

GO

/*******************************************************/
/* Test transaction error handling starts here         */
/*******************************************************/
USE transactionlearning;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
GO

IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @ErrorMessage
        = N'Check 1: Transaction in an invalid or closed state (@@TRANCOUNT=' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
          + N'). Exactly 1 transaction should be open at this point.  Rolling-back any pending transactions.';
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 127);
    RETURN;
END;


ALTER TABLE [b] ADD [a_id] [NVARCHAR](36) NULL;
GO


IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @ErrorMessage
        = N'Check 2: Transaction in an invalid or closed state (@@TRANCOUNT=' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
          + N'). Exactly 1 transaction should be open at this point.  Rolling-back any pending transactions.';
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 127);
    RETURN;
END;

UPDATE [b]
SET [a_id] = [a].[a_id]
FROM [a]
WHERE [a].[a_name] = [b].[a_name];
GO

IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @ErrorMessage
        = N'Check 3: Transaction in an invalid or closed state (@@TRANCOUNT=' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
          + N'). Exactly 1 transaction should be open at this point.  Rolling-back any pending transactions.';
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 127);
    RETURN;
END;

ALTER TABLE [b] ALTER COLUMN [a_id] [NVARCHAR](36) NOT NULL;
GO

IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 1
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage AS NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @ErrorMessage
        = N'Check 4: Transaction in an invalid or closed state (@@TRANCOUNT=' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
          + N'). Exactly 1 transaction should be open at this point.  Rolling-back any pending transactions.';
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 127);
    RETURN;
END;

ALTER TABLE [b] DROP COLUMN [a_name];
GO


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

### My fave references on this topic

There is a wonderful free resource online which digs into error and transaction handling in great detail. It is written and maintained by Erland Sommarskog:

- Part One – [Jumpstart Error Handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)
- Part Two – [Commands and Mechanisms](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html)
- Part Three – [Implementation](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html)

One common question is why XACT_ABORT is still needed/ if it is entirely replaced by TRY/CATCH. Unfortunately it is not entirely replaced, and Erland has some examples of this in his paper, [this is a good place to start on that](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, `XACT_ABORT` only affects a single batch; i.e. everything after the next `GO` is still being executed.

Comment: Hi -- I think you actually need to combine my answer with Grant's, I think we each have a piece of it!

When I run your sample command in SSMS, it gives an additional error:

Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Essentially it looks like the GO  is silently committing the transaction. This is an unusual pattern as Grant says, because 'GO' is not actually TSQL, so this is mixing a batch separator into an open transaction. 

This can also be verified with:

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
DBCC OPENTRAN

Comment: Alright, so if `GO` shouldn't be used inside a transaction but I want a single transaction and need to ensure that the individual statements are executed in that particular order; should I then use semi-colons instead of `GO` or could the order of statements being executed still be changed in the execution plan when there are "only" semi-colons?

Comment: semi-colon is just a statement terminator. For some statements it's, as a friend once said, syntactic sugar (although I always use it). The order of operations that Flyway will follow is the order of the statements. So terminator or no (and I'd suggest using them), you should see that order maintained.

Comment: @GrantFritchey ok semi-colons are no solution here. Point taken. And "order of operations/statements" was the wrong phrasing on my part. I've added another example to the bottom of the question, illustrating what I meant: (1) without `GO` it's not working at all as it appears like the first statement's outcome is not considered in the second statement's execution plan, but at least it's fully aborting the transaction and (2) with `GO`, it works if the data is as expected but only performs a partial rollback in the error case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fundamental to the GO command. It's not a part of the T-SQL language. It's a construct in use within SQL Server Management Studio, sqlcmd, and Azure Data Studio. Flyway is simply passing the commands on to your SQL Server instance through the JDBC connection. It's not going to be dealing with those GO commands like the Microsoft tools do, separating them into independent batches. That's why you won't see individual rollbacks on errors, but instead see a total rollback.

The only way to get around this that I'm aware of would be to break apart the batches into individual migration scripts. Name them in such a way so it's clear, V3.1.1, V3.1.2, etc. so that everything is under the V3.1* version (or something similar). Then, each individual migration will pass or fail instead of all going or all failing.

Comment: I actually want the full rollback, which is not happening at the moment.