# Transact-SQL transaction failing without GO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking at a trivial query and struggle to understand why SQL Server cannot execute it.
Say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [id] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](36) NULL
)
```

And I want to add a new column and set some value to it. So I do the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    ALTER TABLE [t2] ADD [name2] [nvarchar](255) NULL
    UPDATE [t2] SET [name2] = CONCAT(name, '-XXXX')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And if I execute the query, I have

[image]

I know, it failing because the SQL Server executes the query in a different order for optimization purposes, and one way to fix it would be to separate those two sentences with GO statement. Thus the following query will pass without issues.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  ALTER TABLE [t2] ADD [name2] [nvarchar](255) NULL
  GO
  UPDATE [t2] SET [name2] = CONCAT(name, '-XXXX')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Actually, not exactly without issues, as I have to use GO statement which will make transaction scope useless, as discussed [on this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64563382/transact-sql-transaction-rollback-not-working-properly-when-using-go-commands)

So I have two questions:

1. How to make that script work without using GO statement
2. Why SQL server is not smart enough to figure out such a trivial case? (it is more like a rhetorical question)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also you've tagged 2 versions of SQL Server here; both are unsupported, and one is End of Life. What version are you really using? Why have you tagged both?

Comment: Larnu, The same issue exist in all versions at least from 2008 to 2019.

Comment: Then, if a version isn't relevant, don't tag specific versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parser error. When you run a statement it is parsed before hand, however, only certain DDL operations are "cached" by the parser so that it is aware of later. `CREATE` is something it will "cache" however, `ALTER` is not. That is why you can `CREATE` a table in the same batch and then reference it.

As you have an `ALTER` then when the parser parses the batch and it gets to the `UPDATE` statement it will fail, and the error you see is raised. One method is to defer to parsing of the statement:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    ALTER TABLE [t2] ADD [name2] [nvarchar](255) NULL;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE [t2] SET [name2] = CONCAT(name, N''-XXXX'');';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

If, however,  `N'-XXXX'` is meant to be the default value, you could qualify that in the DDL statement instead:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    ALTER TABLE t2 ADD name2 nvarchar(255) NULL DEFAULT N'-XXXX' WITH VALUES;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: the statement I used is just an example and in real life it is way more complicated so usage of sp_executesql  with SQL as a string is not feasible. Regarding your answer, really appreciate it but I don't think it completely true, as if you create the table in the same transaction, then it will pass without GO. I guess it will be parsed in the same way but actually will pass.

Comment: Then you'll need to use `GO` and multiple transactions, @MikhailChibel. But using `sys.sp_executesql` is always feasible; what you  I suspect you mean is you're not sure how to use it. If that is the case, then that is what you should be asking about (in a new question)